# Insert values for rows based on list

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe and a list

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
            'ID': ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB02', 'AB03', 'AB03','AB03', 'AB04'],
            'col.A': ["Yes",np.nan,'Yes','Yes',"Yes",np.nan, np.nan]
    
    }
    )
```

`ids = ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB03']`
`new_col = 'result'`
`met = 'yes'`
`else_met = 'no'`

for every id in list, if they're in the dataframe, I want to set the `new_col` to value in `met` and `else_met` if they're not available.

I tried the following code and it's not working, what am I doing wrong?
`df[new_col] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: met if x in ids else else_met)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy.where` to get the values based on Boolean masking, then assign it back to the new column

```py
df[new_col]=np.where(df['ID'].isin(ids), met, else_met)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
     ID col.A result
0  AB01   Yes    yes
1  AB02   NaN    yes
2  AB02   Yes    yes
3  AB03   Yes    yes
4  AB03   Yes    yes
5  AB03   NaN    yes
6  AB04   NaN     no
```

Since you are struggling with the method mentioned above which can possibly due to different version of the libraries, you can try following alternate solution (however, it is not efficient)

```py
df[new_col]=df['ID'].apply(lambda x: met if x in ids else else_met)
```

Another numpy approach combined with List-Comprehension:

```py
values = [met if x else else_met for x in np.isin(df['ID'].values, ids)]
# ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no']
df[new_col] = values
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
`

Comment: @Zakyl, it should work fine, the code is already test and run. Anyways, you can start a fresh teminal/console then try executing the code after import and defining the dataframe

Comment: @Zakyl, even if you struggle, then try wraping `met` and `else_met` inside the squared bracket: `df[new_col]=np.where(df['ID'].isin(ids), [met], [else_met])`

Comment: Still, I'm getting the same error

Comment: @Zakyl, see the alternate approach in the edited answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `loc` and `isin` to assign *met*, and `fillna` the result with *else_met*:

```
df.loc[df.ID.isin(ids),'new_col'] = 'met'
df['new_col'].fillna('else_met',inplace=True)
```

---

```
     ID col.A   new_col
0  AB01   Yes       met
1  AB02   NaN       met
2  AB02   Yes       met
3  AB03   Yes       met
4  AB03   Yes       met
5  AB03   NaN       met
6  AB04   NaN  else_met
```

Comment: Is it possible to get it done in lambda function?

Comment: Yes it is. But why would you want that? It is not efficient especially when so many other alternatives are available.

Answer (score 2):

```
df['new_col'] = 'else_met'
df.loc[ df.ID.isin(ids), 'new_col'] = 'met'
```

Comment: Is it possible to get it done in lambda function?

Comment: The same thing should work in Lambda as well. However, you will have to add a Pandas layer for dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

you can check for every `id` in `df` if is in `ids`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
            'ID': ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB02', 'AB03', 'AB03','AB03', 'AB04'],
            'col.A': ["Yes",np.nan,'Yes','Yes',"Yes",np.nan, np.nan]
    
    }
    )

ids = ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB03']

new_col = 'result'

df[new_col] = ['yes' if val in ids else 'no' for val in df['ID'] ]

#outputs
ID col.A result
0  AB01   Yes    yes
1  AB02   NaN    yes
2  AB02   Yes    yes
3  AB03   Yes    yes
4  AB03   Yes    yes
5  AB03   NaN    yes
6  AB04   NaN     no
```